# Deshabilitar las funciones de los tres botones(Back, Home, cambiar de app) de android

Tags: java, android, actionbar, android-softkeyboard

Estoy buscando alguna forma de deshabilitar las funciones de los botones de la barra de navegacion para que de esta forma mi app no pueda ser cerrada.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Piensa bien lo que quieres conseguir y lo que te puede implicar. Lo que pides normalmente crea usuarios descontentos que al final saldrán de tu app, la borrarán y de paso dejarán el comentario y voto negativo por quitarles botones que usan normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Junto con recomendarte que en la mayoría de los casos no es una buena idea de forzar un dispositivo en modo "kiosk", te puedo ofrecer algunas soluciones parciales.

**Regresar** es la tarea mas simple. Solamente tienes que hacer en tu `Activity` un override de:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // no vamos a hacer nada aquí
}
```

Desde Android IceCreamSandwich (4) ya no es tan simple de manipular la función del boton `Home`, pero podrías relanzar tu actividad cada vez que pasa al fondo.

Lo que debería funcionar es de relanzar tu app con un nuevo `Intent` con el flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP desde `onStop()`. Eso te debería garantizar en todos casos que tu app persiste en primer plano. Ten en cuenta que en este caso no se va llamar a `onCreate(Bundle b)` pero a `onNewIntent(Intent i)`.

Muy importante es que te aseguras que hay una manera dentro de tu app para salir que funciona en todos los dispositivos, o por lo menos que tu app no relanza automáticamente después de un reinicio. Google cambió la política de modificar estos botones por justamente eso.

Comment: Utilizo una versión anterior del sistema, he probado onBackPressed y funciona bien pero me sería necesario deshabilitar los otros botones también.

Comment: Lo siento mucho pero sigo sin entender muy bien como funciona el FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 0):

> Deshabilitar las funciones de los tres botones(Back, Home, cambiar de
>   app) de android.

En el caso especifico de Home y al cambiar de aplicación, tu aplicación cambia a segundo plano y esta puede ser cerrada cuando el sistema operativo requiera memoria, **esto definitivamente no se puede evitar**. Lo que puedes realizar es guardar los valores necesarios para volver a construir el último estado de tu aplicación en caso de que fuera cerrada.

En cuanto al botón "back" se sobreescribe el método [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())  y simplemente indicamos que no tenga ninguna funcionalidad:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}
```

---

> [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())  Se llama cuando la actividad ha detectado la
>   pulsación del usuario de la tecla de retroceso ("back"). La implementación
>   predeterminada simplemente termina la actividad actual, pero puede
>   anularla para hacer lo que desees.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, lo que estas necesitando es hacer que tu App sea el mismo launcher. De ese modo no se va a poder acceder a el "home" para entrar en otras Apps, y como vos mismo sos el launcher no das acceso a otras aplicaciones. El back se soluciona con el onbackpressed.

Busca informacion sobre el "Koisk Mode".

Te dejo un link que te va a ayudar bastante:
https://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-1

Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto, por lo menos para este ejemplo impide que el botón de regresar funcione, solo agrega el de botón menú y el de home o los botones que quieras modificalo a tu gusto.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```